# Remove color in html page

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the blue color above main and below main. I debug for several days, but just do not know how to fix this bug. Please help.

I attached my Page and my desire page.

```css
body {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;     
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    color: #666666;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}   
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
    background-color: #000033;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
h1 {
    line-height: 200%;
    background-image: url(sunset.jpg);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 72px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav {
    font-weight:bold;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 5px;  
    padding-left: 20px;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:link {
    color: #000033;
}
nav a:visited {
    color: #344873;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
main {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
} 
h2 {
    color: #3399CC;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
h3 {
    color: #000033;
}
dt {
    color: #000033;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.resort {
    color: #000033;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}   
footer {
    font-size: 0.70em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 170px;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: #90C7E3;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 700px;
    max-width: 1024px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}
#homehero {
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(coast.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 170px;
}
#yurthero {
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(yurt.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left:170px;
}
#trailhero {
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(trail.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 170px;
}   
header, nav, main, footer {
    display: block;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Pacific Trails Resort :: Yurts</title>
        <link href="pacific.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="yurthero"></div>
            <main>
                <h2>The Yurts at Pacific Trails</h2>
                <dl>
                    <dt>What is a yurt?</dt>
                    <dd>Our luxuy yurts are permanent structures four feet off the ground. Each yurt has canvas walls, a wooden floor
        and a roof dome that can be opened.</dd>
                    <dt>How are the yurts furnished?</dt>
                    <dd>Each yurt is furnished with a queen-size bed with down quilt and gas-fire stove. The luxury camping experience
                    also includes elecricity and a sink with hot and cold running water. Shower and restroom facilities are located
                    in the lodge.</dd>
                    <dt>What should I bring?</dt>
                    <dd>Bring a sense of adventure and some time to relax! Most guests also pack comfortable walking shoes and plan to 
                    dress for changing weather with layers of clothing.</dd>
                </dl>   
            </main>
            <footer>
                <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2016 Pacific Trails Resort</i></small><br>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
        <link href="pacific.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="homehero"></div>
            <main>
                <h2>Enjoy Nature in Luxury</h2>
                <p><span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special lodging experience on the California North Coast. Relax in serenity with
                panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Private yurts with decks overlooking the ocean</li>
                    <li>Activities lodge with fireplace and gift shop</li>
                    <li>Nightly fine dining at the Overlook Cafe</li>
                    <li>Heated outdoor pool and whirlpool</li>
                    <li>Guided hiking tours of the redwoods</li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span><br>
                    12010 Pacific Trails Road<br>
                    Zephyr, CA 95555<br><br>
                    888-555-5555<br>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer>
                Copyright &copy; 2016 Pacific Trails Resort<br>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is for two separate pages. Without having a working fiddle I would just recommend setting the margin bottom to 0px for the image and margin top 0 for the div with the white background.

You could also the the margin top for the div with the white background to minus (example: margin-top:-20px;). A quick and simple solution is to set margin-top to -30px in ur css for main and that will get you the desired effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/26f8ntwm/

```
main {
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   display: block;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   margin-left: 170px;
   **margin-top: -30px;**
   margin-bottom: 1px;
   padding-top:0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper element has a blue background (#90C7E3), and since `nav` and `footer` don't have a background (i.e. their background is transparent), and they are *inside* `#wrapper`, that wrapper background color is visible in `nav` and `footer`:

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #90C7E3;
    etc.
```

Solution: Just erase the first line from this rule, or give backgrounds to `nav` and `footer`.